# CardView looks different in Pre-lollipop?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I utilize cards to show some information in a Recycler View. It shows the data, but the problem is the view that shows different in Kitkat when compared to Lollipop.

Look at the background color in Kitkat device which I posted below. Card and background looks same color, so it looks awful. But, look the Lollipop device, we can see the differentiation in card and background unlike we see in Kitkat device.

Btw, I'm aware of elevation that works only from 5.0+. But, background color looks different in diff android version?

In Kitkat :

[image]

In Lollipop :

[image]

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/relative" >


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="#85656565"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="This is just a random text that will be changed dynamically. It&apos;s static now but will be update dynamically later"
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <com.github.curioustechizen.ago.RelativeTimeTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="3 hours ago"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="#ffff1f15"
                android:id="@+id/postedDate"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT :**

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
```

In Kitkat :

[image]

In Lollipop :

[image]

Comment: Since the `CardViews` themselves look the same, your problem is not with the `CardViews`. Since the background *behind* the `CardViews` changes, your problem is with whatever is providing that background.

Comment: Right, then what about the  `card_view:cardCornerRadius` ? It doesn't applied to top right and left. I'll update the image to question now.

Comment: @CommonsWare Updated. Please check the card corner radius differentiation now.

Comment: @YuvaRaj  I have also stucked in the same kind of problem..Could u plz help me on that..My question on SO is as :- http://stackoverflow.com/q/42644539/3946958

Comment: @YuvaRaj did you ever solve this issue? I have exactly the same results, everything is find with Android >= 21 but Android <=19 doesn't look good.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay if it's not about CardView then what is the issue? Why does only pre-lollipop Android look ugly? I have ConstraintLayout as wrapper for all my content inside my CardView (which is top wrapper).

Comment: @user924: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing what you are using and explaining, in detail, what "look ugly" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare the issue with KitKat is simply to explain: It just doesn't clip ImageView. We have rounded CardView but ImageView is automatically rounded only on Android >= 21. We don't need to manually add corners for ImageView because every content inside rounded CardView will be automatically rounded to fit CardView well (but not on pre-lollipop devices)