# ImageView scaleType="fitXY" is not working in pre-lollipop device inside the Cardview | Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-cardview

I have `ImageView` which is inside the `CardView` as below in my code. My `ImageView` scaleType="fitXY" is not working on **pre-lollipop** devices.But it looks better on  **Lollipop** devices. Please look at below images.
 [image]
As we see in above image there is white padding around the imageview which i want to remove, I want to look alike image on both pre-lolipop and post lolipop devices. Please help me to short out from the problem. Thanks :)

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgChat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: hey you can check version code and if it is below 21 then you make custom imageview using rectangle with corner radius and set image in custom imageview.

Comment: @Vaibhavi Thanks for urs input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the problem is not short out in **pre-lollipop** devices, We can customize the `ImageView` in rounded Imageview(As in Lollipop devices). We can make the check of the **OS** and customize the imageview according it.

Basically we can use the **Universal image loader** [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) *OR* **Glide image loader** [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to create the application.

**Universal image loader** provided the default RoundedCorners to create the corner of ImageView like this

```
 ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(MainActivity.this));
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))/// RoundedBitmapDisplayer IS THE CLASS BY  WHICH , WE CAN CREATE THE ROUNDED CORNER OF THE IMAGEVIEW
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();
        imageLoader.displayImage("http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/wp-content/uploads/scareface.jpeg", YOUR_IMAGEVIEW,options);
```

In **Glide image loader** , we need to create the Custom class to create the arc of the `Imageview` ,In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36372555/3946958) you find the Custom rounded class to create the rounded arc around the `ImageView`

```
Glide.with(this)
                .load("http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/wp-content/uploads/scareface.jpeg")
                .bitmapTransform(new RoundedCornersTransformation( MainActivity.this,15, 2)) ///RoundedCornersTransformation IS THE CLASS, WHICH YOU NEED TO COPY INSIDE YOURS PROJECT, PLEASE FIND THIS CLASS ON ABOVE LINK AND I AM ALSO PROVIDING THE CLASS FOR IT
                .into(YOUR_IMAGEVIEW);
```

For creating the rounded corner in glide , we need to copy the below class in our project, I have got this class from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36372555/3946958)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.Transformation;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.Resource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.BitmapPool;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapResource;

/**
 * Created by javiergonzalezcabezas on 2/4/16.
 */
public class RoundedCornersTransformation implements Transformation<Bitmap> {

    public enum CornerType {
        ALL,
        TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT,
        OTHER_TOP_LEFT, OTHER_TOP_RIGHT, OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT, OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT, DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT
    }

    private BitmapPool mBitmapPool;
    private int mRadius;
    private int mDiameter;
    private int mMargin;
    private CornerType mCornerType;

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(Context context, int radius, int margin) {
        this(context, radius, margin, CornerType.ALL);
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(BitmapPool pool, int radius, int margin) {
        this(pool, radius, margin, CornerType.ALL);
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(Context context, int radius, int margin,
                                        CornerType cornerType) {
        this(Glide.get(context).getBitmapPool(), radius, margin, cornerType);
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(BitmapPool pool, int radius, int margin,
                                        CornerType cornerType) {
        mBitmapPool = pool;
        mRadius = radius;
        mDiameter = mRadius * 2;
        mMargin = margin;
        mCornerType = cornerType;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<Bitmap> transform(Resource<Bitmap> resource, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
        Bitmap source = resource.get();

        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapPool.get(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        drawRoundRect(canvas, paint, width, height);
        return BitmapResource.obtain(bitmap, mBitmapPool);
    }

    private void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float width, float height) {
        float right = width - mMargin;
        float bottom = height - mMargin;

        switch (mCornerType) {
            case ALL:
                canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
                break;
            case TOP_LEFT:
                drawTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case TOP_RIGHT:
                drawTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM_LEFT:
                drawBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                drawBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case TOP:
                drawTopRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                drawBottomRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case LEFT:
                drawLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                drawRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_TOP_LEFT:
                drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_TOP_RIGHT:
                drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT:
                drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT:
                drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT:
                drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            default:
                canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(right - mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom - mRadius), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(right - mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawTopRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                               float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                                  float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right - mDiameter, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                                   float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom - mRadius), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    @Override public String getId() {
        return "RoundedTransformation(radius=" + mRadius + ", margin=" + mMargin + ", diameter="
                + mDiameter + ", cornerType=" + mCornerType.name() + ")";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This Gap is Result of `CardView` internal padding in Pre-lollipop device. Since in Api < 21 there is no native support for Shadows and Clipping `CardView` recreate these effects through fallback solutions. 
Now if you define a `cardCornerRadius`, in Pre-lollipop devices the `CardView` will apply content padding (Equal to corner radius value) to your content in order to prevent your content overlapping Corners.

To disable this behavior, You can do this in XML:

```
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

or using java:

```
cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false)
```

to disable overlap corner padding.

**Update:** If you really want to achieve the same effect in pre-lollipop device you can try to clip your image yourself using libraries like this one:

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

, So when your content overlap `CardView` the Corners gonna overlap and you will get the same look as post-lollipop devices..

Comment: I Updated Answer, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I have used already this inside the cardview card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" , Than It gives me the new problem that is :-Now image is showing in rectangle without any corner(arc type at the end of all image) in it

Comment: Yea, since in Pre-lollipop there is no Native support for clipping CardView can't clip your view; Hence your view covering CardView Entirely, Blocking the Corners..

Comment: plus one for urs effort :) ...Trying to solve the problem by checking the version of the OS :|

Comment: Thank you, Since you working hard to achieve same effect even in pre-lollipop I updated my answer. hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for urs comment bro..I do not require the third party library.

Comment: Yea, the main idea is clipping your view and overlapping it with CardView, I had a hunch that you wouldn't need a library to do that but given that this is a complex problem that lot of developers trying to solve, they may be other developers reading this question..

Comment: I  have done this by Image library using Glide Or Universal, plz find my answer :P ....Thanks for urs valueable comment dost :)